# Flutter : onSaved event not fired after selected item in MultiSelect

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am using Flutter Multiselect from official - flutter_multiselect: ^0.5.1
everything works fine , but onSaved() event not fired after selecting/deselecting and clicking the save button in MultiSelect Widget. i just wanna print the selected/deselected item in console.

Note : am also trying to get via change() event , its works only if we selecting the option, not works while deselcting.

help me to resolve this problem

Sample Code:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
  ),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: new MultiSelect(
    maxLength: 1,
    maxLengthText: "",
    autovalidate: false,
    dataSource: countries,
    textField: 'country_name',
    valueField: 'country_id',
    hintText: "Select Your Country",
    initialValue: countryID,
    value: countryID,
    required: true,
    validator: (value) {
      if (value == null) {
        return 'Please Select Country';
      }
    },
    filterable: true,
    change: (values) {
      if (values != null) {
        setState(() {
          countryID = values.cast<String>();
          getStatesByCountry();
        });
      }
      //this event emitted while selecting option from multiselect
      //not works on deselecting option from multiselect
    },
    onSaved: (value) {
      debugPrint("on save event");
      print(value);
      //always not emitting
    },
    
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot see whole code, it's hard to tell but I would guess you don't save the whole form like this:

```
void _onFormSaved() {
    final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;
    form.save();
  }
```

I would recommend to follow [this original example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multiselect/example)

Hope it somehow help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i dont know its a correct way, but in my case just cleaned a build and reinstalled packge will emit onchange event while removing items in multiselect,nothing else works me